# How to ensure an HTML video fills the screen of a responsive webpage

Tags: html, css

How do I set the CSS (or other), to ensure the video I am working with fills the screen, both 100% width and 100% (minus the fixed height of the nav bar). Don't mind how it works, i.e. black bars above and beyond or cutting away sides or top of video.

So far this is what I have got:

```
<div class="row content">
  <video autoplay loop muted poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </source>
  </video>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1 class="text-center">Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap, CSS and HTML.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7s75ps/1/). It doesn't show the issue that well, as the window resizes proportionally, but hopefully will help.

Comment: You should post your CSS, or better still make a fiddle.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an absolutely positioned box with black background and make that fill the screen. Adjust the top to account for the menu height.

http://jsfiddle.net/1jz80dws/

HTML

```
 <div class="fill">
    <video autoplay loop muted poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background">
      <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </source>
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fill {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    top:70px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```